# PHP windows 64bit

Tags: php, windows, binary, 64-bit

We have a PHP application installed for a client on his windows server, using Apache and Mysql. Now the client wants to upgrade his server and is asking 
"Does the application, apache web server, and mysql support Windows 64 bit?"

Now, I see there is a mysql version for windows 64bit, but I can't find anything official for Apache and PHP, but only binaries from 3rd-party sites.

Does anyone know if there is an official Apache and PHP release for windows 64bit (or a trustworthy 3rd-party at least)? For Apache I could use IIS so it's not really a problem, so it's mainly PHP I'm interested in.

Alternatively, will there be a problem if I run the standard latest binaries that are offered from the PHP site?

As always, thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK you can just install 32bit version of PHP and it will work just fine. Works fine for me.

Comment: Same here, no problems with 32bit Apache and PHP on my 64bit system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a WAMP stack on 64bit windows system. However there' might be some problems with some dll extensions for example CURL as described [in this article](http://www.andrejfarkas.com/2012/07/wamp-2-2-and-php_curl-dll-extension-problem-on-64bit-architecture/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Windows 7 64Bit and use the XAMPP for 32 Bit.
So you can just install Apache, PHP and MySQL for 32Bit systems on a 64Bit machine.

Comment: Note that there are differences between 32-bit and 64-bit PHP, not least the range of integers supported... it may make a difference